# How can I click the whole row in a list activity with a custom adapter instead of just the image I added?

Tags: android, imageview, listactivity

I'm creating a ListActivity that has only images in the rows.  I can display the images already but when I try to click on the row it does nothing.  I can click on the image that I've added but I would like to be able to click on the whole row like a normal List Activity.  Can anyone tell me how I can do that? Not sure why the code backtick isn't picking up my first line but here it is:

Still haven't been able to solve this problem. Anyone?

```
public class AddNote extends ListActivity {

IconAdapter mAdapter;
private Button btnMove;
private Button btnDelete;
private Button btnSave;
private EditText etDescription;
private int iconPos = 0;
private String server;
private String project;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
    setContentView(R.layout.add_note);
    mAdapter = new IconAdapter(this);
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    mAdapter.addIcons();
    btnMove = (Button) findViewById(R.id.move);
    btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete);
    btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
    etDescription = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.description);
    server = app_preferences.getString("server", "none");
    project = app_preferences.getString("project", "no project");

    btnMove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("Move", "Move");
        }
    });

    btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("Delete", "Delete");
        }
    });

    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (etDescription.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a description", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else
            {
                UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
                saveMapIcon(id, iconPos, etDescription.getText().toString(), "0,0");
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Log.e("Test", "testing....");
    iconPos = position;
}

private void saveMapIcon(UUID theID, int position, String description, String location)
{
    SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();

    String mapIcons = app_preferences.getString("mapNotes", "none");
    if (mapIcons.equals("none"))
    {
        mapIcons = server + "|" + project + "|" + theID + "|" + position + "|" + description + "|" + location + "*";
    }
    else
    {
        mapIcons += server + "|" + project + "|" + theID + "|" + position + "|" + description + "|" + location + "*";
    }
    Log.e("position:", String.valueOf(position));
    editor.putString("idToMove", theID.toString() + "|" + String.valueOf(position));
    editor.putString("mapNotes", mapIcons);
    editor.putBoolean("addingIcon", true);
    editor.commit();
    Log.e("Test", mapIcons);

    Intent intent = null;
    intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GetMap.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public class IconAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    ArrayList<View> imageViews = new ArrayList<View>();

    private Integer[] mIconList = {
            R.drawable.symbol1, R.drawable.symbol2, R.drawable.symbol3, R.drawable.symbol4, R.drawable.symbol5};

    private ArrayList<Integer> mIcons = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public IconAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mIconList.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mIconList[position];
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);
        i.setImageResource(mIcons.get(position));

        return i;
    }

    public void addIcons() {        
        for (int i=0; i<mIconList.length; i++)
        {
            mIcons.add(mIconList[i]);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making a holder in the getView() of my ArrayAdapter and loading it with an ImageView.  I also put it in an AlertDialog because I suspect it may have been having problems with trying to have a list as well as other gui elements on the screen at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Millec8,

This functionality would require you override the function [`onListItemClick()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick%28android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29) in your ListActivity...

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    //your code here
}
```

Comment: I've overridden onListItemClick() and it still only selects just the image. Do I need to turn off focusability or selectability somewhere else for this to work?

Comment: hmmm, i have a custom `ListView` with 3 `ImageViews` and haven't run into this.  could you post your code for the `ListActivity`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there should be an easier way to do this, but from a similar question I had with a custom ListView, I did the following:

Create and replace the ImageView with a new custom ImageView, something to this effect:

```
public class NoClickImageView extends ImageView {
    @Override
    protected void onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Basically, make it dead, where it won't handle any sort of touch or click events. If you need it to be selectable, you can add extra methods like `setSelected()` and then call those in your `onListItemSelected()` method. But I'm fairly certain that using the above should do it.

Comment: I replaced the ImageView and it still is behaving the same way.