# Displaying a list of images

Tags: android, android-listview, listactivity

I would like to display a list of images that the user can select.  When the user selects a row, the row will stay highlighted.  I've displayed a list of images using a ListActivity but I'm having trouble with selecting the whole row instead of just the ImageView I have in it. What's the best way to go about displaying this information?  Should I use radio buttons instead of highlighting the row to show selection? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Make your question more specific and clear and post some code also explain in a better way.

Comment: @Dinesh Sharma I posted a question last week trying to solve the issues with the ListView in a ListActivity, however it didn't yield any helpful answers so I decided to see if there was a different way to go about it.  The other question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791580/how-can-i-click-the-whole-row-in-a-list-activity-with-a-custom-adapter-instead-of)

Comment: @Milec8:ok,I will check the issue...

Answer (score 0):

Question and answers are already provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058291/highlight-listview-selected-row).

Comment: So I shouldn't try to do selection because in touch mode there isn't selection etc. But I still need a way of showing images that can be selected. My question still stands, staying within the "android" way of doing things how should I display these images?